# PL/SQL: varchar2 as IN parameter to function not working

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL function like this:

```
FUNCTION find_by_items(items IN varchar2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  o_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  open o_cursor for select a.something from my_table a where a.item in (items);
  return o_cursor;
END find_by_items;
```

This always returns an empty cursor.

If I run it with, for example:

```
select find_by_items('''one'', ''two'', ''three''');
```

I get an empty cursor.

If I put the sql statement in a string and revise the function like:

```
FUNCTION find_by_items(items IN varchar2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  o_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  strSql varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  strSql := 'select a.something from my_table a where a.item in (' || items || ')';
  open o_cursor for strSql;
  return o_cursor;
END find_by_items;
```

And I call the function the exact same way:

```
select find_by_items('''one'', ''two'', ''three''');
```

I get the results I expect (not an empty cursor)

--

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to make the first way work, because using a string means that it's more prone to runtime errors rather than compile errors - which in my particular case is not preferable.

Thanks

Comment: Using IN on varchar will check whether one of your items has a name of '''one'', ''two'', ''three'''. Of course there's no such item. You need to split those into temp table, and then select from the table.

Comment: Have you tried to convert your string to a list? E.G. with dbms_utility.comma_to_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first implementation will never work as you expect, because Oracle resolves the Query as follows:

```
select a.something from my_table a where a.item in ('''one'', ''two'', ''three''')
```

and what your want is

```
 select a.something from my_table a where a.item in ('one', 'two','three')
```

split and store your string parameter values into a varray so you can use the following form:

```
 select a.something from my_table a where a.item in (table(varray_var));
```